# Окончания (-ы / -и) сущ-х мн.ч. им.п

Tags: окончания

Существует ли правило, по которому выбирается -ы или -и при образовании мн. числа в им.падеже?

1-е скл, ж.р - лампа - ламп**ы**, но бумага - бумаг**и**

2-е скл, м.р. - стол - стол**ы**, но парк - парк**и**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Обычно Ы пишется после твердой основы, а И ― после мягкой**: стол ― столы, карусель ― карусели, земля ― земли, пчела ― пчёлы, то есть чередование согласных в основе не происходит.

**Но после заднеязычных Г, К, Х пишется И,** написания ГЫ, КЫ, ХЫ нехарактерны для русского языка.

**Также существуют особые правила для основ на  шипящие:** лыжи, огурцы.

Comment: "Ы пишется после мягкой основы, а И ― после твердой"? А может, наоборот?

Comment: Ну да, я как раз именно это имела в виду.

Comment: Спасибо. Вот как-то так и думала, но не была уверена.